# SuspenseList not working as I would expect in React 18

Tags: reactjs

I've got what to me feels like a trivial example of `SuspenseList` in this component and it returns an error I don't understand (at bottom of this question).  I thought All I had to do was wrap `Suspense` components inside a `SuspenseList` component and I should get similar behavior to if I had just wrapped them all in a single `Suspense` component.

Here is my non-working component:

```
import { Suspense, SuspenseList } from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

function ShowData() {
  const { data } = useSWR("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2", fetcher, {
    suspense: true,
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <SuspenseList revealOrder="forwards">
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading1</div>}>
        <ShowData />
      </Suspense>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading2</div>}>
        <ShowData />
      </Suspense>
    </SuspenseList>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

Answer (score 0):

SuspenseList has been removed from the first version of React 18 releasing so it's just not there anymore. I think moved to the next release whenever that is.

Comment: Any way to know if SuspenseList is really back in RC1? I posted a separate question here on that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356344/react-18-rc1-released-with-no-notes-and-it-appears-suspenselist-is-back