# React 18 RC1 Released with no notes and it appears SuspenseList is back

Tags: reactjs

On Twitter, several Facebook employees alluded to a React 18 RC1 and now it has released. I can not find any notes on it.  I notice SuspenseList is back but not sure if it works.  When I upgrade an app I wrote with React 18 to RC1 I get a cryptic error I can't resolve.

https://libraries.io/npm/react/18.0.0-rc.1-next-f468816ef-20220225

This is my project:  https://peterkellner.net/2022/01/23/most-polluted-cities-air-quality-with-react-18/.   https://github.com/pkellner/airquality

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: The server could not finish this Suspense boundary, likely due to an error during server rendering. Switched to client rendering.
```

Comment: You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24125